# Why is in this snort rule EOF missing at '.'

Tags: http, pcre, snort

I have a snort rule I want to import in an IDS.

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"FOX-IT - Trojan - Possible CobaltStrike C2 Server";
  flow:to_client;
  content:"HTTP/1.1 200 OK |0d0a|"; fast_pattern; depth:18;
  content:"Date: ";
  pcre:"/^HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\nContent-Type: [^\r\n]{0,100}\r\nDate: [^\r\n]{0,100} GMT\r\n(Content-Length: \d+\r\n)\r\n/";
  threshold:type limit, track by_dst, count 1, seconds 600;
  classtype:trojan-activity; priority:2;
sid:21002217; rev:3;)
```

I get the error:

> Validation failed: Invalid or unsupported PCRE token: [...] ERROR:
>   Unsupported PCRE syntax: missing EOF at '.'

When I edit the PCRE from

```
pcre:"/^HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\nContent-Type: [^\r\n]{0,100}\r\nDate: [^\r\n]{0,100} GMT\r\n(Content-Length: \d+\r\n)\r\n/";
```

to

```
pcre:"/^HTTP 200 OK \r\nContent-Type: [^\r\n]{0,100}\r\nDate: [^\r\n]{0,100} GMT\r\n(Content-Length: \d+\r\n)\r\n/";
```

(so deleting `/1.1`), it says the syntax is valid.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like the backslash after `HTTP` should possibly be escaped. What IDS and what version are you importing into? I’ll message the rule author (a colleague) in the morning for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the HTTP header:

```
 /^HTTP/1.1 200...
```

The PCRE is delimited using forward slashes.  You have inadvertently left a bare slash in your expression.  Additionally, you have a dot there that you likely do not mean to.  You will want to make adjustments such as:

```
 /^HTTP\/1\.1 200...
```